# How to reuse Preferred language select?

Tags: custom-fields

There is the ***Preferred language*** field in ***Communication Preferences*** which allows to choose the contact's preferred language.

However when I try to create custom fields for a contact's second, third language, I don't find ***Language*** as a choice among the other ***Data and Input Field Types*** What would be the recommended way to make the language select like in ***Preferred language*** available for re-use in custom fields?

With all the languages in a select field defined and available somewhere, what I try to avoid here is that I need to re-enter all these languages by hand for my custom fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this need today, and wrote a general version of the extension @ñull wrote above.  This lets anyone take advantage of this feature without knowing how to code: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/languagecustomfield

Answer (score 3):

In CiviCRM, custom fields have the ability to re-use options from another custom field, but not from a core field like *Preferred Language*. So this is not currently possible via the UI.

2 Solutions come to mind, both using small amounts of custom code:

1. Write a short script that uses the api to fetch all languages and then copy them into the options of one of your custom fields. Then re-use those same options in 3rd, 4th language fields.
2. Write a tiny extension that implements [hook_civicrm_customFieldOptions](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_customFieldOptions) and populates those options dynamically by outputting the languages in the system.

Comment: I put following in my extension:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/com2/cda5bb57d2adf8cc3bbd
which worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

My solution for this was to

1. Setup Field with Alphanumeric and Select Properties, assigning it to any existing option set.
2. Directly in the Database: Find Table: "civicrm_option_group" In that table find the option group you are trying to use (e.e: Languages). Take note of that row's "id".
3. Directly in the Database: Find Table: "civicrm_custom_field" In that field find the field you created in Step 1.
4. In the row of that field, edit the column: "option_group_id" to the id number you notated in Step 2.

This worked for me when trying to use the Languages list.

Comment: In some ways I like this solution better than my own.  I might update my extension to use this method.  The advantage is that you can uninstall the extension and it will continue to work.  There's a theoretical performance boost too, but it's a minimal difference.